# How to make a function use a variable outside the function, but in a method of a class

Tags: python, function, class, variables, global

I am trying to make a function that will be able to access a variable from outside the function. However, this variable needs to be defined in a class.  I'll define a simplified function of what I am trying to do in code for clarity.

```
class Stuff():
     def __init__(self):
         print("Initialized")

     def forward(self,x):
         y=4
         x=func(x)
         return x



def func(x):
   global y
   return x+y

stuff = Stuff()
print(stuff.forward(4))
```

So, I am trying to make func(x) use the y defined in the "forward" method, but when I run this code, I get the error "global name y is not defined". Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: make `func(x, y)` and call it with your `y` variable

Comment: The `global` statement is used to declare a name being 'not local' in a function that alters it. You put it in the wrong place.

Comment: What you *really* should do, however, is pass in `y` as an argument to `func()`. Why do you think you need a global in the first place?

Comment: Put differently: any name *not* being bound to (assignment is one form of binding) is *already a closure or a global*. `y` doesn't get bound to in `func()`, it thus a global name. `y=4` binds `y` in `forward()`, making it local, automatically. `global y` changes the scope there, because it is there that it matters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Should i delete this question since it seems the answer lies in a different post?

Comment: You can't, because there is an upvoted answer (which has a strange, incorrect first paragraph, at least in this context), that you marked accepted. And you don't need to, either, duplicate posts *can* help future visitors find the canonical post on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. A *member* variable belongs to a specific instance of a class. You have to know the instance to do that, so you'd better pass `y` to your function as well.

You could do the opposite though. use `global` in the `forward` function to define a global `y` variable, and then access it from the `func`. However, don't. It's bad practice, always. Pass `y` to func instead.

Comment: This has nothing to do with member variables. a) that's not a concept in Python. b) if you are talking about instance attributes, then there is no `self.y` involved here. It's *just another local*. Methods are no different here from regular functions.

Comment: Put differently: **you can do what the OP wants, trivially**, but the OP shouldn't.

Comment: How can I define a global variable in a method? btw, I know what I'm asking sounds silly, but I need it for a larger program I am writing.

Comment: @RohanSingh: Just put `global y` before `y = 4`. the `global` keyword means: when I refer to `y`, use the global one, if it exists, or create it, if it doesn't

Comment: @RohanSingh: Methods are just functions. They are not special when it comes to scoping rules. See the duplicate, and my comments. Put `global y` *in the `forward` function body*.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answers, I guess this question boiled down to creating a global variable in a method.

Comment: @RohanSingh: ok, creating a global variable is the same, whether in a function or a method